# Connect DBeaver to PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, windows, authentication, dbeaver, postgresql-13

I've been using PostgreSQL 10 and 12 on Windows successfully with DBeaver in the past. Now I've set up a new development machine and installed the current PostgreSQL 13.0.1 and the current DBeaver 7.2.4 on Windows 10.2004. When connecting to the local Postgres server, I got the message that a connection wasn't possible in the Postgres 10 style and I should check the hb_pga.conf entries.

I went to my hb_pga.conf file and changed all of the shiny new `scram-sha-256` entries back to the old `md5` and restarted the database server.

But DBeaver won't connect. Is this a problem with the latest DBeaver or Postgres or what? Has anybody managed to get these two to talk to each other with the latest versions?

Unfortunately DBeaver seems to be based on Java and is limited to JDBC which doesn't seem to be maintained anymore so it can't use the current Postgres authentication scheme. I've looked for multi-DBMS alternatives to DBeaver but couldn't find any that looks convincing. Same old problem, good GUI database clients are very expensive, the free ones are often of poor quality. I hoped DBeaver was a good solution.

Comment: What is the error you get? Did you change the existing passwords after changing to scram authentication? The JDBC driver for Postgres is most certainly still supported and probably you are simply using an outdated driver. Just download the current one from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 2):

Changing authentication to md5 in pg_hba.conf won't help you if the password hash is already in the scram format.  You need to `set password_encryption TO md5` and then change your password (possibly back to the same thing it already is) to get the password stored in the md5 format.

> JDBC which doesn't seem to be maintained anymore

JDBC is maintained.  Perhaps you can't figure out how to upgrade it, but that is a different problem than it not being maintained.

SCRAM does work with JDBC starting in version 42.2.1 (current version is 42.2.18)

Comment: Oh, then maybe DBeaver isn't supported anymore, despite bringing out new versions. This is what I found about it: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2122

Comment: @ygoe: that issue only repeats an _error message_ from the server if an outdated JDBC driver is used. This has nothing to do with the driver being "unsupported".